# Packing Django, Python and Chromium together

Tags: python, django

I would really like to distribute something like Electron for Python web applications build using Django framework. I didn't find a solution yet, so I would aks if there is one available. If not, how could I create one easily on my own?

I use the latest versions of Django and Python. I would also use Chromium, because I have to care about accessibility for screen reader users and I know that Chromium is fully accessible to that users group.

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to use Django for this. You can find toolkits for building Python desktop apps easily enough, and Django isn't intended for this use case. Electron uses Javascript at least in part because it's still primarily a client-side technology, so it's a better fit.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Which ones do you mean and do they use Chromium?

Comment: You wouldn't use Chromium for that use case. Most platforms for desktop or mobile apps support a webview of some kind (Phonegap relies on it), but you generally get a better, more integrated experience with the native UI elements. There is a list of UI frameworks at https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming

Comment: @MatthewDaly Yes, but they are too hard to learn at the moment, the native UIs and the most are not accessible. I would use something like I described, because I want to have the web interface feeling, but withouth the need of a web browser manually started and pointed to the localhost loopback.

Comment: The native UI's aren't that hard and plenty are cross platform. If you want to be able to build it using web technologies then Javascript is a far, far better fit for that use case. You can't use Python to manipluate the DOM in the same way and the ecosystem for that kind of thing is much richer with Javascript.

Comment: @MatthewDaly It is a dependency, so I can't switch. And for a blind user, they are really.

Comment: You're suggesting that blind users can't use user interfaces other than web browsers, which I'm pretty sure is not true.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Developping a GUI as a blind person is quite difficult. I am blind and have to develop something that works fine and can be used as either a desktop application and a web application without completely rewriting it.

Comment: Ok, if you want to develop an application that works as both a desktop and web app, my advice would be to make it a single page web app. The API back end can be Django (I recommend Django REST Framework for this) or any other back end technology, but the front end will need to be Javascript. You can then either make the front end a progressive web app so it will work offline in the browser, or use something like Electron as a container for the client-side Javascript.

Comment: Your front end assets can live in a separate Git repository that you set as a submodule for both the desktop and web apps, making it simple to update both. You will need to be able to detect the context in which it's running, to determine what to do if it needs to work differently in the web and desktop app, but that should be easy enough.

Comment: That way you can keep the Django backend on the server where it belongs and easily have multiple frontends interacting with it. If offline functionality is necessary then you can store the data in whatever storage system is most appropriate.

Comment: @MatthewDaly And how would you write the front-ends you talk about? I which programming- / scripting lagunage? With the use of which framework? I am really curious, because it doesn't sound bad, it it is possible without too much rewrite work.

Comment: The front end would need to be done with Javascript (or a language that compiles to it, such as Typescript) to fulfill that requirement. Pretty much any Javascript client side framework would do the job - Angular, Vue and React would all be suitable.

Comment: @MatthewDaly And how would you connect with the back-end? I have never done this.

Comment: You send data back and forth between the API and frontend via AJAX. I build Phonegap apps for a living and I use exactly this method to communicate between the app and backend.

Comment: @MatthewDaly I never learnt JS or Ajax. I only have knowledge of HTML, PHP and Python.

Comment: You shouldn't have much trouble learning it if you already know PHP and Python. Javascript can be a bit odd in places, but it's not a hard language, and it's pretty ubiquitous these days, and there's not really any alternative for front-end stuff other than languages that compile to it. Ultimately you'd probably find yourself needing to pick it up at some point, so why not now? And if you use something like Vue.js you don't have to deal with the rather unpleasant DOM API.

Comment: @MatthewDaly This is maybe a possibility.